# HP Smart Array cache benefits

Tags: hp, hp-smart-array

I have to decide if we should buy Smart Array Controller with 2 or 4 gb cache. I currently have a P840/4G and a P440ar/2G for testing. Is there a way to check the cache usage while running a file transfer?

Comment: You should simply run tests based on your estimated workload, and see if there is any difference between those two. After all, you are looking for a solution that is best for your workload, and testing the workload is the best way to find it out.